# Separating digits from a float

Tags: c, integer, digits

I need a simple function that has 3 variables:
l (left), m (middle), and r (right)
So

```
int l,m,r
```

And when I put in the number 27.2
l should become 2
m should become 7
r should become 2
I can think of dividing the left 2 by deviding by 10 and then cast to int but the other 2 numbers?

Comment: Upload your code.

Comment: `sprintf` the float into a string (with the desired number of decimals, that must be a requirement) and then process the string char by char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your number be stored in x.

```
float x = 36.2;
x = x*10;
int r = (int)x%10;
x = x/10;
int m = (int)x%10;
x = x/10;
int l = (int)x%10;
printf("%d, %d, %d",l, m, r);
```

Comment: Do note that this solution would work for 10.0 - 99.9, and may not work for other values beyond those. Let me know if you need to consider cases beyond those range as well!

Comment: Actually I do, it is for temperature display on separate 7-segment (digital 8) display blocks. So temp could be < 10 and even negative :) >99.9 would not be a realistic scenario.

Comment: Amended the solution! Not sure how you'd like to handle the negative cases, but if need be, you can use the abs function (i.e. `abs(x)`) to make it positive!

Comment: `abs(x)` is not the right function to use to make `-12.3` a positive.  Recommend `fabsf()`.

Comment: @Niels For world-wide distribution which obliges C & F, >99.9 would be a realistic.  [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_weather_records#Highest_temperatures_ever_recorded) 56.7 °C (134.1 °F) to −89.2 °C (−128.6 °F).